# Target is null error in browser dev tools

Tags: dom

I am trying to insert newly created elements (rows and cells) into a table (via javascript) above a row that has an ID of "dynPop".  When I attempt to do this, I get the following error

**TypeError: target is null**

Here is the HTML of the table...

```
<table>
  <tr id="dynPop">
    <td  style="color:white">
      blah blah blah blah blah
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the code to insert the new row and cell before it...

```
$rownumber = 1;
var target = document.getElementById('dynPop');
//Populate member table with chapter image row 
var $CHAP_IMAGE = $out[1];
var olr1 = document.createElement('tr');
var old1 = document.createElement('td');
var olt1 = document.createTextNode($CHAP_IMAGE);
old1.appendChild(olt1);
olr1.appendChild(old1);
$rowname = 'row' + $rownumber;
olr1.setAttribute('name', $rowname);
target.insertBefore(olr1, target);
$rownumber++;
```

Any thoughts as to why this javascript code is not working ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I"m not sure without seeing the rest of your HTML, but I think the main problem is that your JavaScript is executing before the DOM loads.

You might try putting your JavaScript into a function that gets called on the body element's `onload` event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>asdf</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function doThing() {
        $rownumber = 1;
    var target = document.getElementById('dynPop');

        var $CHAP_IMAGE = "$out[1]; ";
        var olr1 = document.createElement('tr');
        var old1 = document.createElement('td'); 
        var olt1 = document.createTextNode($CHAP_IMAGE); 
        old1.appendChild(olt1); 
        olr1.appendChild(old1); 

        $rowname = 'row' + $rownumber;
        olr1.setAttribute('name',$rowname);
        target.insertBefore(target, olr1);
        $rownumber++;

    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="doThing()">
   <table>
     <tr id="dynPop">
      <td  style="color:white">
    blah blah blah blah blah
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table> 
</body>
</html>
```